# Create link for android app items that users can click to view it in the app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, share, sharing

I have created my first app which has sharing functionality (social media and email) for my items.

I want to extend sharing to include a link of my item in the app. Meaning: when I share an item on facebook (etc.)  it will be accompanied by a link. When the user clicks that he will be taken to see the item inside my android app.

I don't know if this is possible at all. Is there a way I could generate a link for that will take the user to a specific activity displaying an item?

Any pointers and suggestions on how to approach this are welcome.

Thanks in advance,
Jonida

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called deep-links. You can implement them easily:

https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

If you are looking forward to implement them only for Facebook, you can use their service for that:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads-engagement

Comment: Thanks. Good to know there is a name for it! Will do the suggested reading! :)